# When spouse visa is refused to a Nigerian spouse of an EU citizen what is the appeal process?

Tags: visa, eu-spouses, refusal

I am a Greek national living in Cyprus Republic for three last 3 years. I recently married my husband , a Nigerian national who I met in the Turkish side ( North Cyprus). Because of the problem with the island’s division he could not enter the Greek side unless he went back to Nigeria and requested a spouse visa to fly through the national borders. So this is what he did.

He applied for the visa at the consulate of Cyprus in Lagos and we did all the appropriate steps, including a bank guarantee of 850€. The consulate asked for additional information to verify the validity of our wedding. We were told that the ministry of foreign affairs in Cyprus was not convinced that the wedding took place in Istanbul Turkey ( which makes it valid) as opposed to the North side of Cyprus where it would not be recognized. We provided all the necessary documents, including tickets, boarding passes, hotel bookings and of course copies of the official Turkish wedding registration, as well as my copy of the wedding registration in Greece!

However without further discussion they refused him his visa saying that they could not verify the authenticity of the documents provided! I went myself today to the Consular Affairs department of the Ministry in Cyprus and found the person in charge of my case, showed them the original documents in my position and asked for the refusal to be lifted. To which their answer was that the documents are indeed OK, valid, but since they already refused they cannot change their decision. I have to go to high court and contest their decision, or wait 3 months to re apply.

Is this true? Can they do this? Do I have grounds to insist they re-examine the refusal? Since all our documents are correct? It is their mistake not ours!!! They confirmed that what I showed them is indeed a valid wedding certificate! Please advise what I can do! I cannot wait that long to reapply and the costs for lawyer’s and courts are too high! It is crazy!

Comment: Note: this was originally asked at [Travel.SE] as [Refusal of Cyprus spouse visa to Nigerian husband of Greek citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/131960/19400).

Comment: Did you apply for the visa under the freedom of movement directive ([2004/38/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616))?  (If you paid a fee for the application, then the application was not handled according to the directive.  The bank guarantee also should not have been required, which suggests that the application may have been made or received under national law.)

Comment: You might want to hide personal information on that picture.